# Could someone explain why/how this sample scene kit code works?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am working with scene kit and am trying to make a first person game. I found this sample code for making the first person camera with a pan gesture. Everything works but I do not understand what is going on here. Could someone explain what is happening?

```
    func lookGestureRecognized(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    //get translation and convert to rotation
    let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
    let hAngle = acos(Float(translation.x) / 200) - Float(M_PI_2)
    let vAngle = acos(Float(translation.y) / 200) - Float(M_PI_2)

    //rotate hero
    heroNode.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: hAngle), impulse: true)

    //tilt camera
    elevation = max(Float(-M_PI_4), min(Float(M_PI_4), elevation + vAngle))
    camNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: elevation)

    //reset translation
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the same code, with a few additional comments:

```
func lookGestureRecognized(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    // Create Translation variable, containing the 
    // "distance" traveled by the finger since the last event
    let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)

    // From this distance, calculate how much the camera should move
    // 1) horizontally, 2) vertically using angles (FPS controls)
    let hAngle = acos(Float(translation.x) / 200) - Float(M_PI_2)
    let vAngle = acos(Float(translation.y) / 200) - Float(M_PI_2)

    // Apply the horizontal angle to the Hero node as a force to
    // Make it rotate accordingly (physics body use forces to move)
    heroNode.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: hAngle), impulse: true)

    // Use the other angle to look up and down, clamped to ±pi/4
    elevation = max(Float(-M_PI_4), min(Float(M_PI_4), elevation + vAngle))
    // Apply the new angle to teh camera on the X axis
    camNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: elevation)

    // Set the translation to 0 to avoid accumulation 
    // the next time the event is triggered
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

This should help understand, let me know if you need more details on how it works!

(Note: the "Distance" is actually a 2D Vector)

EDIT: here's a better explanation of the angle:

```
    let hAngle = acos(Float(translation.x) / 200) - Float(M_PI_2)
```

First, the translation (so pixel distance on x) is divided by 200. This is to both slow down the movement and (unsafely) keep x between -1 and 1.

Acos gives the arc cosinus of a value. The result is between 0 to pi and (to simplify) only works for x from -1 to 1. Here's a graph for it: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=acos%28x%29-pi%2F2

Since we want to move in positive and negative directions, we remove half of the max value (M_PI_2, which is pi/2) to keep the result within -pi/2 to pi/2

In the end, if you move your finger 200 pixels in a direction, you would look pi/2=90° on your screen.

Comment: Still have a few questions.  How do we have the "distance" if the translation in view is just a cg point? Is it the coordinates from 0,0? Also could you explain the acos() line in more detail? That was the most confusing to me. Thanks!

Comment: The distance is the vector of the movement the finger made since the last event. If you moved 10 up and 5 left, it would be something like  (5,-10). The last line puts that back to 0 every time the event is called. I'll update the answer explaining acos in a second.

Comment: Thanks I think I get it now appreciate the help!